# how to split path names. 

Tags: tcl

the input is  C:\test\deva\tcl\newfiles\aug.txt

the output should be "test" "deva" "tcl" "newfiles"

"aug.txt" files or anyother ".txt" files at the end of the string should not be printed.

Comment: Change question title to "pathname splitting" or "extracting components of a pathname".

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Reverting back to my original solution and adding some bits...

Assuming this is a filepath not a random string that happens to need to be split \

[File split](http://tcl.tk/man/tcl8.0/TclCmd/file.htm#M29) does almost what you want, it returns the path split up as a list . you also want to use lrange to select everything but the volume i.e something like (untested)

```
lrange [file split $path] 1 end-1
```

so you don't have c:\ which should be the first element in the list returned by file split

Additionally you may want to use file dirname first if there is any chance you will get directory path instead of a filename e.g. same caveats re testing

```
lrange [file split [file dirname $name]] 1 end
```

Comment: i couldn't understand what you mean.
what i need to know is how to separate strings of words from a given sentence with "\" inbetween them.

Comment: sorry changed my mind a few times on how to do it - is it clearer now

Comment: C:\test\deva\tcl\new.txt is a input the particular string such as test, deva, tcl must be shown in the output terminal. the rest C:\ and new.txt should be let off.

Comment: sorry that i didn't understand what you mean with the lrange command.

Comment: lrange strips off the first part of the list because it should contain c:\ and you don't want that

Comment: yeah i dont want the first part and also it should strip off the part which contains ".txt" which might probably come at the end of the list

Comment: as we can strip off the first part like you suggest is there a way to strip off the part which contains ".txt" characters in the string\

Comment: also one more doubt how can it strip off the first c:\ from the input as the input would be considered as a string and not as a list as there is no space between the input.

Comment: file dirname also does that (input is a string output is a list)

Comment: $path contains C:\tcl\bin\deva\new.txt when executed using: lrange [file dirname $path] 0 end output is : C:\tcl\bin\deva what this command does is its stripping off the last element but not the first as it is considering the contents in the $path as a string. if executed this way: lrange [file dirname $path ] 1 end its giving null or empty spaces as it is considering the "C:\tcl\bin\deva" as a single element of the list "path"

Comment: yep you are right - going back to my first solution which was file split and lrange - confused this with dirname and dont have tcl here to test at the moment

Comment: that is what i was expecting. its working absolutely fine. thanks jk.

Answer (score 0):

`[split]` combined with `[lrange]` can do what you want but in a non-portable way.

One way to make this more portable would be to use the result of calling `[file separator]` for splitting instead of bare "\".  But since "/" are also okay both in Tcl and Windows the real way to go portably would be to repeatedly call `[file dirname]` on the string and extract the last component of the returned pathname using `[file tail]`.

For more info read [this](http://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl8.5/TclCmd/split.htm), [this](http://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl8.5/TclCmd/lrange.htm) and [this](http://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl8.5/TclCmd/file.htm).

Comment: every suggesstion is working fine but its not doing what it needs to be done.
the problem is when using lrange with file dirname, the command assumes the given input which is stored in the variable "path" as a single string hence its difficult for us to break it into pieces.

Comment: @deva, I forgot the obvious thing that `[file split]` does what you need (as finally mentioned by jk in their answer), so I'd just delete my post.